# Remove values in first two columns except the row where a value in the first column equals the name of the sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a solution to a second part of the code.
I have a table with 5 columns containing about 70 records (every time different number) and I need to create new spreadsheets (each tab is named as a record number in the first column) for each record where values for other records in the first two columns will be hidden(removed/deleted). The first row and the last row of the table shouldn't be hidden as they contain columns' headers and Total formulas (5th column contains formulas as well).

I've managed to create a code to solve the first part of the problem of creating  spreadsheets with all data and changing names for those tabs. But I still cannot figure out how to keep only values for one record in a spreadsheet and hide/remove/delete values in the first two columns for other records.

Here is the code I have, would be grateful for any help!

```
Sub Create()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xNumber As Integer
    Dim xName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp - 1).Row
    Set rg = Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    xNumber = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy the current sheet")
    For I = 1 To xNumber
        xName = ActiveSheet.Name
        ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xName)
        ActiveSheet.Name = ws.Range("A" & I + 1).Value

        With rg
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveSheet.Name
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.Clear
        End With

    Next
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe: Create a range of column A row 2 to lastrow -1. Use the .find function to check for the value you are looking for and store the found row of the cel in a variable. Check if the row isnt 2 or lastrow-1 and then delete the ranges A2:B foundrow-1. Find lastrow again, then delete range A3:B lastrow-1......I'm not able to write you the code in VBA as I have no availability to Excel on this machine. Good luck Sir

Comment: Thanks for the reply JvdV! Unfortunately, I'm not that proficient in VBA yet, just started writing some simple codes combining parts of other codes I found online. It would be great to have an example how it should be done, so I could moving forward.

Comment: Hope the answer helps you out. Be gratefull, done this on my Saturday eve haha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer with some code that will:

- Loop through all your sheets
- Looking for current sheet name (If not there then do nothing)
- Delete/clear cells untill there is just the 3 rows left

Adjust to your liking

```
Sub DoStuff1()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long, FR As Long
Dim CL As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn the screen refresh off

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets 'Loop through your sheets
    WS.Activate
StartHere: LR = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'Get the dynamic last used row
    Set CL = WS.Columns(1).Find(What:=WS.Name, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not CL Is Nothing Then
        FR = CL.Row 'Get the row which is the value
        If FR > 2 And FR < LR Then 'If larger than 2 but smaller than last used row then
            WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(FR - 1, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            GoTo StartHere
        ElseIf FR = 2 And FR < LR Then 'If FR = 2 but still some rows between FR and LR
            WS.Range(Cells(FR + 1, 1), Cells(LR, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            GoTo StartHere
        ElseIf FR = LR And FR > 2 Then 'If A is the lastrow with a value but rows between 2 and FR
            WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(FR - 1, 2)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            GoTo StartHere
        Else
            'If there is only the startrow, the foundrow with value and the very last row left...
        End If
    End If
Next WS

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turn the screen refresh back on
End Sub
```

**EDIT: Second option, clearing cells instead of deleting**

```
Sub DoStuff2()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long, FR As Long
Dim CL As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    WS.Activate
    LR = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Set CL = WS.Columns(1).Find(What:=WS.Name, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not CL Is Nothing Then
        FR = CL.Row
        If FR > 2 And FR < LR Then WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(FR - 1, 2)).ClearContents
        If FR < LR And FR > 2 Then WS.Range(Cells(FR + 1, 1), Cells(LR, 2)).ClearContents
        If FR = 2 And FR < LR Then WS.Range(Cells(FR + 1, 1), Cells(LR, 2)).ClearContents
        If FR = LR And FR > 2 Then WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(FR - 1, 2)).ClearContents
    End If
Next WS

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @JvdV. This should work, but I need to leave all rows in the table and only remove/hide values (make them "white") in the first two columns (other values should remain) where the value in the first column is not equal to the name of the sheet...

Comment: Your question clearly stated: remove/hidden/delete. Either way, it can be done through clearcontents instead of delete.

Comment: thank you, I changed the code to clearcontents but it throws an error "91": "Object variable or With block variable not set" in this row:
FR = WS.Columns(1).Find(What:=WS.Name, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

Comment: How did you dim FR? And WS? Have you included to loop through sheets? What have you done... explain more or include a snippet of your code. What I have send you before worked. Obviously you can’t simply replace delete to clearcontents

Comment: I haven't changed a lot... 
just removed Goto StartHere, changed .Delete Shift:=xlUp to .ClearContents and added extra line to the first IF check to clear values above and below the row with the value:
        If FR > 2 And FR < LR Then 
            WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(FR - 1, 2)).ClearContents
            WS.Range(Cells(FR + 1, 1), Cells(LR, 2)).ClearContents

Comment: That won’t work. I’ll try edit the code I have you sometime soon

Comment: I think you were close. My guess is you haven't activated the worksheets which will lead to that specific error. Rest of your adjusments seemed fine. If the asnwer works for you now, pls mark as solved.

Comment: Still get the same "91" error in the line with FR = WS.Columns(1). Find(...  Also why do we need to add extra "IF" (duplicate condition) if there is an option to place both statements to clean cells above and below the value row in one IF (I might missing something here)?

Comment: Can you check if the ws.name is actually there in the range? About the ifs, haven’t payed much attention to them. If you can add them together... then that’s all the better 

Comment: Yes, the ws.name is in the range. Those names were derived from the original table when I created its copies. Maybe there is a problem in parameters of the Find function?

Comment: On which exact worksheets does this error occur? The second sheet in the loop?

Comment: How I can check that? I'm not very proficient in debugging VBA codes.. 
  It looks like the error pops up right away in the first iteration.

Comment: To me the code works perfect. If you go through the code with F8 you can see if it actually errors out on the first or second iteration. To me it seems you may not have included the ws.activate line at the start of each loop.

Comment: I copied your code and tried to run it - get the same error. Using F8 it shows that the error appears on the first iteration. I checked that I have ws.activate line right after For statement..

Comment: I might have one idea why it doesn't work in my case but I don't know how to fix that..   
The name of my first sheet is not in the range (first column) we're searching in, so I assume it returns "Nothing" and triggers the error..   
Do you know what should I do to avoid that?

Comment: I double checked by removing the sheets that doesn't have their names in the range that the code works. But if you have at least one sheet that doesn't have its name in the range, the code throws an error. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: That’s why I included the line in my answer: it needs the worksheet name in the range 100%. Also I asked you after if it actually has the name in it. Will edit the answer sometime soon.

Comment: I have updated both pieces of code with a piece of code that will first check if the name excists. If not, it will do nothing and go to next worksheet. Hope you have been helped out now. Tip: Next time, just make sure your question is a 100% clear. Saves everyone a lot of time.